# How to make 2 reference id into one id in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a dimension table called Client_Dim

```
ID|client number|name          |address        |city
4 |5555         |Mike Herald   |6 Han Street   |Boston
9 |5555         |Mike Herald   |11 Main Street |Boston
```

I need to change Client_Dim ID number 9 into Client_Dim ID number 4 because it is the same person. I'm using Client_Dim ID number 4 as a reference to another table.

I want an output like this:

```
ID|client number|name         |address         |city
4 |5555         |Mike Herald  |11 Main Street  |Boston
```

How can i accomplish this ?

(This is my current code, which doesn't work)

```
update Client_Dim
set address = '11 Main Street'
where client number = 5555
```

Comment: If your column name contains a space, you'll need to escape it: `[client number]`. Removing a redundant row can never be done with an `UPDATE`; that'll require a `DELETE`. It's unclear from your question if you just need to fix up these two rows, or if you need a general approach for merging duplicate rows, which is more involved (especially if there are foreign keys pointing to the table).

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert yes, I need a general approach for merging duplicate rows because of foreign keys pointing to the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the DDL of your table but it sounds like you have an index on the ID column, probably an auto-increment and it's referenced in another table.

Usually this type of tasks is done using SQL-Proc that takes in consideration some SQL aspects by fetching data from the meta-model to identify if the FK is cascading on delete for example and behave accordingly.

But it sounds like you are working with some prototype data and you just want to fix it quickly.
Your query in this case is missing a couple of square brackets and it should be good.

```
UPDATE Client_Dim
SET address = '11 Main Street'
WHERE [client number] = 5555
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not so simple. You need these steps:

1. You have to find a proper logic which defines you which row should be kept in Client_Dim table (which works for all cases). For example:

   - Always keep row data of the biggest ID for the lowest ID inside a "customer_code" group
   - Or, keep row data of that row which have the lowest differences from the row with the lowest ID
   - etc.
2. You have to update all foreign keys in all referencing tables in Client_Dim_ID from 9 to 4
3. Then your can update the row with ID = 4 to the new address in Client_Dim
4. Delete the row with ID = 9 from Client_Dim table